# Is there a correlation between Brownian motion and cosmic microwave background radiation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, cosmology, cosmic-rays

Is there any correlation between Brownian motion, the phenomenon of osmosis - compared to cosmic microwave background, the Noise we see in analog television?

Brownian motion or pedesis (from Greek: πήδησις /pˈɪːdiːsis/ "leaping") is the random motion of particles suspended in a fluid (a liquid or a gas) resulting from their collision with the quick atoms or molecules in the gas or liquid. Wiener Process refers to the mathematical model used to describe such Brownian Motion, which is often called a particle theory.[1][better source needed]
This transport phenomenon is named after the botanist Robert Brown. In 1827, while looking through a microscope at particles trapped in cavities inside pollen grains in water, he noted that the particles moved through the water but was not able to determine the mechanisms that caused this motion. Atoms and molecules had long been theorized as the constituents of matter, and many decades later, Albert Einstein published a paper in 1905 that explained in precise detail how the motion that Brown had observed was a result of the pollen being moved by individual water molecules. This explanation of Brownian motion served as definitive confirmation that atoms and molecules actually exist, and was further verified experimentally by Jean Perrin in 1908. Perrin was awarded the Nobel Prize in Physics in 1926 "for his work on the discontinuous structure of matter" (Einstein had received the award five years earlier "for his services to theoretical physics" with specific citation of different research). **The direction of the force of atomic bombardment is constantly changing, and at different times the particle is hit more on one side than another, leading to the seemingly random nature of the motion.**

Noise, in analog video and television, is a random dot pixel pattern of static displayed when no transmission signal is obtained by the antenna receiver of television sets and other display devices. The random pattern superimposed on the picture, visible as a random flicker of "dots" or "snow", is the result of electronic noise and radiated electromagnetic noise accidentally picked up by the antenna. This effect is most commonly seen with analog TV sets or blank.
There are many sources of electromagnetic noise which cause the characteristic display patterns of static. Atmospheric sources of noise are the most ubiquitous, and include electromagnetic signals prompted by **cosmic microwave background radiation**,[1] or more localized radio wave noise from nearby electronic devices.

Comment: while the analogy with the CMB is weak, many think that the big soap of the void fields seem to the brownian case

Comment: Concerning the phenomena of atomic vibrations and EMR: what do you mean by, "the big soap of the void fields"? Thank You

Comment: Please do not vandalise your question.

Comment: To expand on what Greg said, completely editing out the content of your post like that is considered vandalism and is against our site rules.

Answer (score 5):

Cosmic microwave background radiation is very "cold", i.e.  the average energy is very low. It started in the region of atomic levels, order of electron volts, but is now [order of magnitude lower](http://universeinproblems.com/index.php/Time_Evolution_of_CMB#Problem_17:_energy_density_evolution) and the only interactions it can have with atoms in the atmosphere are elastic scatters.

The origin of the CMB radiation at  [380.000 years after the Big Bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe#/media/File:History_of_the_Universe.svg) is when the photons decoupled from the rest of the matter as matter combined into atoms and became neutral. The CMB is a snapshot of how matter was distributed at that time, and reflects a randomness, but it is on a scale much larger than the Brownian motion and gravitational theory enters in the explanation. The small [inhomogeneity displayed](http://map.gsfc.nasa.gov/media/121238/index.html)  is attributed to the seeds of galaxies and clusters of galaxies.

So no, there is no connection to Brownian motion, other than basic randomness.